# Как обратиться к инпуту внутри самописного компонента через formControlName

Tags: javascript, angular2, forms

Angular 4. Помогите разобраться с ControlValueAccessor (насколько я знаю, для решения этой задачи нужен именно он). Есть компонент  . В нем есть инпут. Мне нужно взаимодействовать с инпутом этого компонента через реактивные формы с помощью formControlName. Как это реализовать?

parent.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="tasksForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<input type="text" formControlName="name">
<input type="number" formControlName="phone">
<input type="text" formControlName="email">

<app-test formControlName="task"> </app-test>

<button type="submit" md-raised-button>  Ок </button>
```

parent.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.tasksForm = this.fb.group({
    name: 'Vasya',
    phone: '12345',
    email: 'vasya@mail.ru',
    task: '777'
  }, {
    validator: (formGroup: FormGroup) => {

    }
  })
}
```

test.component.html

```
<input> </input>
```

Нужно, чтобы инпут внутри компонента test был связан с переменной task

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите код, что у вас есть. И объясните подробнее - что значит "взаимодействовать"?

Comment: Подозреваю, что вот эта статья должна ответить на все вопросы
https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html